# How to make AVAudioPlayer stop playing background music after 30 minutes even when in background?

Tags: iphone, ios, timer, avaudioplayer, nstimer

I use AVAudioPlayer to play music for children to fall asleep.

The music also plays when the screen is locked or when the app is in the background.
When it plays too long the children wake up again. A developer friend said iOS suspends scheduled NSTimer in background so it is not reliable.

What other option do I have to to make music stop after 30 minutes even if device is in background?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at these:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3

[How to run the timer in background of the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916633/how-to-run-the-timer-in-background-of-the-application)