# NSTimer as background thread

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, thread-safety, nstimer

I need to ping a server at fixed intervals. I am currently using the following:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f 
                                 target:[Socket getInstance] 
                               selector:@selector(sendHeartBeats) 
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:YES];
```

This calls function `sendHeartBeats` at an interval of 5 sec.

Do i need to call this on a separate thread so that my main thread will not be affected?

Comment: If you want not to run on main thread check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304702/how-do-i-create-a-nstimer-on-a-background-thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSTimer`s, as well as the related `NSRunLoop`, do not affect (nor are aware of) the threading behavior of your process. Both just use the current thread.

This means that you have to care about threads on your own. `NSTimer`, in conjunction with `NSRunLoop` give you the opportunity to schedule timed tasks on a given thread.

You can use a timer on the main thread or start a new thread, add a runloop to it and start a timer on that background thread.

Anyway, when using threads, you have to be aware of thread safety issues. In this case this means making the `Socket` class (singleton?) thread safe because it is probably used elsewhere in your app.

Answer (score 2):

Well to answer the question, the answer is "no" you don't need a background thread in order to avoid disrupting the main thread with a timer.

At least that's true of the `NSTimer` mechanism, however if the method that is called by the timer spends a lot of time *doing something* then the answer would "yes", you should call it in a background thread.  However you are required to provide a *runloop* in that background thread in order for `NSTimer` to work, and then it gets complicated.

Therefore if *I* was going to do something in a background thread I would avoid `NSTimer` and simply do something like:

```
while (YES) {
    [[NSThread currentThread] sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];
    if ([[NSThread currentThread] isCancelled])
        break;
    doThing();
}
```

The thread that started this background thread would then call `[thread cancel]` in order to cancel that thread.

Answer (score 0):

> Do i need to call this on a separate thread so that my main thread
>   will not be affected?

No need.

Timers work in conjunction with run loops. To use a timer effectively, you should be aware of how run loops operate—see **[NSRunLoop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSRunLoop)** and **[Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i)**.