# NSTimer seems to be slowed down by MKMapView panning?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, timer

In the `UIViewController`, I have an `NSTimer` scheduled to fire every 1 second, using `scheduledTimer` method, so I could update a `UILabel` in the view every second. But the problem is, the `NSTimer` firing seemed to be delayed whenever I pan around the `MKMapView` that is inside also inside the `UIView`. So the delay results in the `UILabel` not updating uniformly, which is not good to see. Could the delay caused by `MKMapView` panning taking too much resources? How could I schedule the `NSTimer` so that there is no delay however I pan the `MKMapView`? (Note, however, that I didn't schedule the `NSTimer` on some kind of background thread, it is in the main thread.) Thanks.

Comment: Does setting up the timer in the background thread to do the calculation, then using `dispatch_async` code to get main thread to update the UI, work ? The dispatch_async example is shown in this asnwer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283652/understanding-dispatch-async

Comment: How are you scheduling the timer?  You need to schedule it with `NSRunLoopCommonModes` if you want it to fire while scrolling/panning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(...)` to create your timer, it will be added to the current runloop with mode `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`. The timer will not fire while your app is busy with event tracking, i.e. if you scroll around in a UIScrollView or if you do any other interactions with your UI.

You can create a unscheduled NSTimer and add it to the runloop yourself, if you use `NSRunLoopCommonModes` as mode the timer will fire while you interact with the user interface.

```
let timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("timerFired:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
```

---

For further information, the question [NSDefaultRunLoopMode vs NSRunLoopCommonModes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7222449/457406) contains a nice explanation about the different runloop modes.

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem...the app registers for background location updates, and the CLLocationManager I use to get location updates is defer-updates-enabled. I tried to add the timer to the run loop with NSRunLoopCommonModes, but it seems that the system kills the app when it runs for too long. I think it is because the NSTimer is taking up NSRunLoop when the run loop should be inactivated.

Comment: so invalidate the timer if the app goes into the background, and recreate it when the app comes into the foreground again

Comment: Thank you, your genius suggestion solved my problem.