# NSTimer Repeats not working for me

Tags: objective-c, timer, nstimer

**Problem, runs once.**

```
-(void)firingLogicForPlayer:(Player *)player {

    if (player.playerTargetLock) {
        if (!_fireRateTimer) {
            _fireCounter = 0;

            _fireRateTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(burstControl:)
                                                   userInfo:player.name
                                                    repeats:YES];

            [_fireRateTimer fire];

            BOOL timerState = [_fireRateTimer isValid];
            NSLog(@"Timer validity is: %@", timerState?@"YES":@"NO");
        }
    }

}

-(void)burstControl:(NSTimer *)theTimer {

    NSLog(@"burstControl Initiated");

    NSString *playerName = (NSString *)[theTimer userInfo];

    Player *player = (Player *)[self childNodeWithName:playerName];

    if (_fireCounter < 5) {
        [self playerBeginFiring:player];

        _fireCounter++;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"this ran to kill timer");

        [_fireRateTimer invalidate];

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self firingLogicForPlayer:player];
        });
    }

}
```

`2015-09-16 13:37:44.964 ***[20592:3367845] burstControl Initiated
2015-09-16 13:37:44.974 ***[20592:3367845] Timer validity is: YES
2015-09-16 13:37:45.147 ***[20592:3367845] hit made`

This is what logs, how the logic works is, `firingLogic` is initialised on a target lock. So the timer should run 5 times before being invalidated because of the `_fireCounter` counter. timer begins burst control, checks firecounter if firecounter is < 5 it fires a bullet, increases the firecounter. if the firecounter > 5 it invalidates the timer, and dispatches it to run again after 1.5 seconds.

However, the problem is that the timer is only running once. Yet, it's valid after the initial fire. Pretty confused.

Comment: please provide us the implementation of playerBeginFiring method.

Comment: You have to add it to the `NSRunLoop`. Otherwise you can use `+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats`

Comment: @LucaD You should add an answer, as that is correct I reckon.

Comment: Spot on guys, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add it to the `NSRunLoop`. Otherwise you can use `+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats`

Comment: `[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:_fireRateTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];` ?

Comment: Yes. It depends on which mode you want to add it. Please check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222449/nsdefaultrunloopmode-vs-nsrunloopcommonmodes

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code

```
if (!_fireRateTimer) {
    _fireCounter = 0;
    _fireRateTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(burstControl:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];

    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:_fireRateTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    BOOL timerState = [_fireRateTimer isValid];
    NSLog(@"Timer validity is: %@", timerState?@"YES":@"NO");
}
```

Thanks :)